# Bound an app destiny to another app Android

Tags: android, sharing

I have an Android app which do a lot of things, among them is the streaming video. I have particular necessities so use a custom video player. To avoid crash of the whole app for video problems I have the video player in a separate app.

I managed to avoid it appearing in the menu but unfortunately in Settings--Manage Application I see the video player app and of course it can be uninstalled.

I'd like the player being totally dependent from the main app, that is to say not showing in the Manage Application menu and uninstall it only if the main app is uninstalled.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. An app can be uninstalled any time.

But you can check the existence of your player app and ask the user to reinstall it, if it's missing. You need to ask him in the first place anyway.